# How to use json in menu Angular5 NODEJS

Tags: json, node.js, angular, rest, web-services

Well, I have been reading, and I can't find a solution for this. I'm starting with this project. I want to know how to use a service with GET method like this https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axhir and use it in my menu. This is how my code is written. I'm using a template NGX-ADMIN but they don't have any documentation.

**page.components.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MENU_ITEMS } from './pages-menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-pages',
  template: `
    <ngx-sample-layout>
      <nb-menu [items]="menu"></nb-menu>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ngx-sample-layout>
  `,
})
export class PagesComponent {

  menu = MENU_ITEMS;
}
```

**pages-menu.ts**

```
import { NbMenuItem } from '@nebular/theme';
export const MENU_ITEMS: NbMenuItem[] = [
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    icon: 'nb-home',
    link: '/pages/dashboard',
    home: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'CONFIGURACIONES',
    group: true,
  },
  {
    title: 'Usuarios',
    icon: 'nb-keypad',
    link: '/pages/ui-features',
    children: [
      {
        title: 'Buttons',
        link: '/pages/ui-features/buttons',
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to use a web service like, this example https://api.myjson.com/bins/1axhir, instead of the Constant Array give me a hand please. TY

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score -1):

Angular is only used for FrontEnd and for making API you need to use Node.js or any other Backend framework.

if you want i can give you the node.js code for the same.

Also for integrating the API in angular application, you need to use observeables and subscribers

Comment: Yes, I'm using Node.js for the backend.